# How to map a C# string keyword to Mediator command or query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr

In one of the Web API project we are receiving a string keyword as a payload parameter. We need to map that string/keyword to execute respective Mediator query/command.

Example: If API action payload is { "action" : "GetAllOrders" } So we need to call GetAllOrders query. This way we have many actions which are returning Object response. note- We only have one action method forr everything (weird but it is how it is)

we can write

```
if(action == "GetAllOrders") then _mediatr.Send(query, .. );
else if(action == "GetAllProducts") then _mediatr.Send(query, .. );
else if(action == "GetAllCustomers ") then _mediatr.Send(query, .. );
```

We can write switch case or many if else but ofcourse we are looking for something nice pattern or approach. Thanks.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could use reflection to get a (self defined) type with a matching action name, get a ctor from that type, call it (maybe with further parameters from the request) and call Mediatr with this instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR) library, you can easily find it in Nuget Package Manager.

Then you can define your action method like this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> MethodName( ApiRequest a piRequest, [FromServices] IMediator mediator)
{
    var a = await mediator.Send(apiRequest);
    return a;
```

and then declare your handler class like this.

```
public partial class YourHandler : RequestHandler<ApiRequest, ApiResponse>
{
    protected override ApiResponse Handle(ApiRequestrequest)
    {
        //Write your logic here
        //and return response
    }
```

**Edit:** Based on the last comment added by the OP.

So it all depends on how loosely coupled the handler you would like to implement this. if there are very fewer conditions you could use if else to switch but if there are many you will end up breaking (SOLID principles ). in this case also you could have different handlers. you can have a base response class and derived classes for each response. so if your return type is the same but the handling together is different then it's of no use using the Mediator pattern. having different handlers will help you in such a situation when you want to modify only a particular handling. there will be changes only in your particular handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. we have same setup as you mentioned but specific requirement. which I have updated in my question with example.

Comment: @KPP please check the answer now. I have modified it as per your comment and last edit

Comment: Hi Vivek, Yes we already have different handlers for everything, so in a way its loosely coupled at our end. However the API action method has third party interface which we are implementing and has single entry and exit point. So currently we have many conditions implemented using switch case. We are looking for something where we can map incoming string/keyword to specific command/query without any hard-coded string mappings to avoid ifelse or switch case etc. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @KPP have you tried Dictionary? or define in config/JSON file and read from it to avoid if else

Comment: Hi Vivek, We can keep the mapping settings in dictionary/json/config/db etc but the point is not about where to keep the mappings. but the point here is to avoid any static mapping through any means of storage. So looking for something dynamic/runtime mappings which could make sense in this context.